# req.user is undefined node + express + passport + mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

when i use

```
console.log(req.session);
```

i have message

```
Session {cookie:{ path: '/',_expires: null,originalMaxAge: null,httpOnly:true },passport: { user: 5b427a2d117d7c3f6087db8a } }
```

but using

```
console.log(req.user);
```

give me `undefined`

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/posts');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error"));
db.once("open", function(callback){
    console.log("Connection Succeeded");
});

var User = require("../models/user");
var Post = require("../models/post");
var Girl = require("../models/girl");
//load passport strategies

require('../config/passport/passport.js')(passport);

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// For Passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db
    })
}));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Authorization method:

```
 app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
       username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (!user) {
        res.status(401).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
      } else {
        // check if password matches
        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
          if (isMatch && !err) {
              // if user is found and password is right create a token
              var token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), 'nodeauthsecret');
              res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
          } else {
              res.status(401).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
          }
       });
    }
});
```

Method where try to take user

```
    app.post('/add_girl', (req, res) => {
    var db = req.db;
    console.log("-------------");
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log("-------------");
    //var userId = req.userId;
    var name = "Asuna";
    var level = 1;
    var newGirl = new Girl({
        //userId: userId,
        name: name,
        level: level
    });

    newGirl.save(function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        res.send({
            success: true
        });
    });
});
```

Please help. How I understand user saved in sessions, but how I can take him i don't understand

Comment: what is your expected output in user? Is it `5b427a2d117d7c3f6087db8a`? Also what does console.log(req.body) gives you?

Comment: Yes it is. Console.log(req.body) gives me { title: '', description: '' }

Comment: Can you try console.log(req.session.passport.user);

Comment: If I try it, I catch error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what I needed is add

```
app.post('/add_girl', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: true}),(req, res) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the passport session ?

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: How I understood, yes.  

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

this code I wrote in last lines of the first code block in this question

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

Take passport.initialize and passport.session above mongo session

Your code should look something like this

```
require('../config/passport/passport.js')(passport);

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// For Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


// Replacing your app.use(passport.session()); with the one you've written 
//      with all other options

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db
    })
}));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Currently you're writing `app.use(passport.session())` twice.

Comment: unfortunately, result of console.log also undefined

Comment: you mean `console.log(req.user)` or `console.log(req.body)` or `console.log(req.session.passport.user)` ?

Comment: console.log(req.user);->undefined

console.log(req.body); ->{ title: '', description: '' }

console.log(req.session.passport.user); ->TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: Actually it was my bad I edited the answer, please check again as the sequence of middlewares matters in express.

Comment: this didn't help... 
results of console.log the same

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using low version express session (< v1.5), you have to import cookieParser to use session middleware like this.

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
   var session = require('express-session');
   var app = express();
   app.use(cookieParser()) // before use session middleware
   app.use(session({secret: 'your secret'}));
   ```
2. And ordering of middlewares can be a problem.
3. If you are using a HTTP connection, you have to remove the secure option like below.

   ```
    app.use(session({
      secret: 'your secret',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      // cookie: { secure: true } // remove this line if you are using a HTTP connection
   }))
   ```